# Session validation issue in PHP online server

Tags: php, session

I have set `$_SESSION['admin']=1` after login form validation.
After that the page was redirect and check `$_SESSION['admin']` value and load contents.
It was worked fine in local. But it can't in online linux server. Any help..?

**admin.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $admin = 0;
   if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
      $admin = $_SESSION['admin'];
   }
   if($admin == 0){
?>
<form action="" class="login">
     <label>User Name :</label>
     <input type="text" class="uname"/>
     <label>Password :</label>
     <input type="password" class="pwd"/>
     <input type="submit" class="lSubmit" value="SUBMIT"/>
     <p class="alert lAlert">test alert</p>
</form>
<?php }elseif($admin == 1){ ?>
     <h1>Welcome Site Admin..!!</h1>
<?php } ?>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.lSubmit').click(function(){
    var name = $('.uname').val();
    var pwd = $('.pwd').val();
    $.post("validation/login.php",{name:name,pwd:pwd}).success(function(data){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if(obj.success == 1){
            $('.alert').css('color','#067800');
            window.location = "/admin.php";
        }else{
            $('.alert').css('color','#CC0000');
        }
        $('.lAlert').text(obj.msg);
        $('.lAlert').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    return false;
});
```

**validation/login.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
 $err['success'] = 0;
 $err['msg'] = '';
 if($name == ''){
  $err['msg'] = 'Name required';
 }else if($pwd == ''){
  $err['msg'] = 'Password required';
 }else if($name != 'admin'){
  $err['msg'] = 'Wrong username';
 }else if($pwd != 'admin'){
      $err['msg'] = 'Wrong password';
 }else{
  $err['msg'] = 'Success';
  $err['success'] = 1;
  $_SESSION['admin'] = 1;
 }
 echo json_encode($err);
?>
```

When I run this , it was successfully made validation and if username and password is **admin** then it shows **Success** in alert.  But after it was redirected and again the form only loaded in online server. But in local the welcome text was loaded. But in other pages in online the session works fine. Can anybody help me?

Comment: many things might be wrong, check everything from web server/modules/php.ini

Comment: @GeoPhoenix The session works fine for other pages.. But problem was $_SESSION['admin'] variable only.It was not able to set

Comment: We'll need more information than "it doesn't work". Did you get an error of some sort? What testing and debugging have you done? We don't have access to your stuff, so we can only work with what you've already done. If you've conducted some tests, we can interpret the results; but if you just tell us "it doesn't work", we have no idea where to go for answers.

Comment: Answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11700712/970721

Answer (score 0):

My only guess would be that usually session starts automatically with most development kits like xampp

On real servers most of the time you have to start it manually with session_start()

Comment: In this case i have start session manually using session_start().

Answer (score 0):

add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

at the start of your script and check any errors and post back. My guess is is that you have some permissions problem on the server.