# yii flash message not displaying after redirection in view page

Tags: php, yii, flash-message

flash messages was working fine in local when i moved it into production(cpanel) its not displaying. I am not getting any error or warning.

In controller, i am setting flash like this

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Slider updated Successfully.");
```

and in view,

```
<?php if (Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('success')): ?>
<div class="success">
    <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success'); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yii flash messages are stored in the PHP session variables.
Are you able to set Session variables? Perhaps this will come in handy ([Not able to set session variable in online server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700617/not-able-to-set-session-variable-in-online-server))

Comment: thankyou.. i had PHP session problem. its solved and working fine now